# get() set() memcached listening on UDP using Python

Tags: python, udp, memcached, python-memcached, pylibmc

**Question**: How to `get` `set`, `memcached` listening on `UDP` only, using Python (any of the production level Python bindings)

---

**What I have done/tried so far**:

Making the memcached listen on UDP only - I specified the OPTIONS in memcached config:

```
OPTIONS="-p 0 -U 11211" # -U for UDP port and -p for TCP port
```

Verification:

```
# netstat -nlp|grep memcached
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211           0.0.0.0:*                           12095/memcached     
udp6       0      0 :::11211                :::*                                12095/memcached
```

The problem is, I didn't get to verify i.e. performing `get` and `set` or simply put **I didn't get it to work**.

I have looked into the Python memcache bindings- the 2 widely used ones (reliable, to be used in production) `python-memcached` and `pylibmc`.
For `python-memcached` I didn't find any explicit mention for specifying UPD only or any check if the memcached is listening on TCP or UDP. 
For `pylibmc`, I though found a [mention](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/reference.html#pylibmc.Client):

> To specify UDP, the server address should be prefixed with "udp:", as
>   in "udp:127.0.0.1"

To verify `pylibmc`:

```
>>> import pylibmc
>>> mc_tcp = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"], binary=True, behaviors={"tcp_nodelay": True, "ketama": True})
>>> mc_udp = pylibmc.Client(["udp:127.0.0.1"], binary=True, behaviors=None)
>>>
>>> mc_tcp.set('udp_key', 12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_pylibmc.ConnectionError: error 3 from memcached_set: CONNECTION FAILURE
>>>
>>> mc_udp.set('udp_key', 12)
True
>>>
>>> mc_udp.get('udp_key')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_pylibmc.NotSupportedError: error 28 from memcached_get(udp_key): ACTION NOT SUPPORTED
```

To verify `python-memcached`:

```
>>> import memcache
>>> mc = memcache.Client([('127.0.0.1', 11211)])
>>> mc.set('key', 12)
0
>>> mc.get('key')
>>>
```

---

A similar question - [memcached listeing on UDP with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374750/memcached-listeing-on-udp-with-django)