# memcached listeing on UDP with Django

Tags: python, django, udp, python-memcached, pylibmc

**Question**: I am not able to get `memcached` listening on `UDP`, to work (`get` `set` `delete`) with Django.

---

I have the memcached listening only on `UDP` `11211`, as I have mentioned in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055900/get-set-memcached-listening-on-udp-using-python). What I have tried so far:

1.Setting **`CACHES`** to use **`python-memcached`** Python binding. get and set didn't work with simple settings i.e. `'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211'`, so tried specifying `udp` explicitly (using this [mention](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/reference.html#pylibmc.Client) as the rationale):

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': 'udp:127.0.0.1:11211',
        'TIMEOUT': None,
    }
}
```

gave:

**`ValueError: Unable to parse connection string: "udp:localhost:11211"`**

2.Setting **`CACHES`** to use **`pylibmc`** Python binding:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': 'udp:127.0.0.1:11211',
        'TIMEOUT': None,
    }
}
```

The server ran fine - to further verify:

```
>>> import django
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.set('udp_key', 12)
>>> cache.get('udp_key')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 84, in get
    val = self._cache.get(key)
NotSupportedError: error 28 from memcached_get(:1:udp_key): ACTION NOT SUPPORTED
```

---

**P.S.** Don't make it a memcached on **`TCP`** vs **`UDP`** debate

---

A similar question - [get() set() memcached listening on UDP using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055900/get-set-memcached-listening-on-udp-using-python)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have been able to explore the library [libmemcached](http://libmemcached.org/) that [pylibmc](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/) uses does not support `get` operations with UDP.

I have traced the cache call to `get` up to `libmemcached` and I have found [the following code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tangent-trunk/libmemcached/1.2/view/head:/libmemcached/get.cc):

```
    ...
    if (memcached_is_udp(ptr))
    {
      return memcached_set_error(*ptr, MEMCACHED_NOT_SUPPORTED, MEMCACHED_AT);
    }
    ...
```

that coincides with your error as **pylibmc**'s `get` method is mapped to **libmemcached**'s `memcached_get` method in the file with the code above (`/libmemcached/get.cc`).

I have install and configure the same environment in my own machine and I have got identical results.

Nevertheless, the `set` operation seems to work perfectly as I have observed running **memcached** in debugging mode.

I have also tried to provide different locations ((PROTOCOL + IP + PORT)s separated by **;** in the **LOCATION** field) for the cache mixing TCP/UDP, but the library DOES NOT SUPPORT mixing protocols either and returns an error.

```
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
            'LOCATION': 'udp:127.0.0.1:11211;127.0.0.1:11211',
            'TIMEOUT': None,
        }
    }
```

All the previous facts are confirmed by the documentation of [libmemcached](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_behavior.html?highlight=udp#MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_USE_UDP).

The option of using `django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache` as a backend is also discarded as it only uses TCP sockets (`SOCK_STREAM`) for connecting to **memcached**.

**UPDATE**: [python-memcached-udp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached-udp/) is now a pip package. Its mantainer [is open to add more features if needed](https://github.com/idanmo/python-memcached-udp/issues/3). If you are interested we definitely could work on creating a new Django cache backend for Memcached with UDP.

Comment: Thanks for digging into it. As it's clear, even pylibmc don't support get, now the question remains - how can we have memcached on UDP to work with Django, using some production level package.

Comment: I have found https://github.com/idanmo/python-memcached-udp that could be used as a starting point. I have forked it to support python 3 at https://github.com/mfeliu/python-memcached-udp. If you are interested, we could write a django cache backend that uses it.